# eclipse frequent crash

Tags: 14.04, eclipse, crash, adt

I've been using eclipse (the one bundled in ADT) extensively for about a year and had no problems. But from yesterday, without any particular change (no eclipse update, no new plugins, ..., **EDIT: however, I updated Firefox yesterday**) it started crashing. If crashes a few seconds after I run it.

I even reset workspace, but got no success.

I was using opedjdk 7, reverted back to openjdk 6, again with no success.

Here's the console output when the crash happens:
http://pastebin.com/fT3VLkAt

And here's the more detailed error log it generates:
http://pastebin.com/UyiU8wQq

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 in x86-64 architecture. ADT version is v22.0.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not the correct answer, but the famous workaround seems to suppress it for now:

- Add this to `eclipse.ini` file:
  `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

Comment: is it working now??

Comment: Yes, no crash for 3 hours. Before this, it was crashing 5-10 seconds after starting.

Comment: Holy mother of workarounds! I was having the exact same issue but this seems to have fixed this!! But how does this work exactly?

Comment: it does not work for me
any other options?

Comment: Still works .. for some reason :)